# $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,2]$, and $f(0)=f(2)=1,|f'(x)|\leq1$. Please prove that $1 \leq \int_0^2 f(x)dx\leq 3$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

> $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,2]$, and $f(0)=f(2)=1,|f'(x)|\leq1$.  Prove that $$1 \leq \int_0^2 f(x)dx\leq 3$$

I have a stupid idea which is using the graph of the function.

Actually, I want to know any other solution about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^2 f(x)dx= \int_0^1 f(x)dx+\int_1^2 f(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(x)dx+\int_0^1 f(2-t)dt$

You can see that for $f(2-t)$ we have the same conditions as for $f(x)$, so we will just need to prove that:

$\frac{1}{2}\leq\int_0^1 f(x)dx\leq \frac{3}{2}$

1) $f'(x)\geq-1, f(0)=1$ so:

$f(x)\geq 1-x$ and $\frac{1}{2}\leq\int_0^1 f(x)d$

2) $f'(x)\leq 1, f(0)=1$ so:

$f(x)\leq 1+x$ and $\frac{3}{2}\geq\int_0^1 f(x)d$

Answer (score 2):

Looking at graphs is completely fine, as long as you get an actual argument out at the end. Looking at graphs can often be a good idea when you are searching for such an argument.

For instance, the end points and the restriction on the derivative, using the mean value theorem, implies that the graph of $f$ will necessarily be contained in the square with corners at
$$
(0,1), (1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2)
$$
and from there it's not difficult to see that the integral must be somewhere between $1$ and $3$.

If you want to do it less geometrically, define a function $f_0$ whose graph is the lower two edges if the square and a function $f_1$ whose graph is the upper two edges:
$$
f_0(x) = |x-1|\\
f_1(x) = 2-|x-1|
$$ Then $f$ must lie between these two functions (again by using the values at the end points, the restriction on the derivative and the mean value theorem), so the integral of $f$ must lie between the integrals of these two functions.

Comment: The topic starter thinks that it's a stupid idea and he looks for other solutions.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Which is why, in the second part of my answer, I solve this without actually looking at the graph (yes, I refer to the graph, and in particular the square, as I describe $f_0$ and $f_1$, but that's just a minor convenience and not necessary at all). I also point out that it is _not_ a stupid solution (it isn't) and they shouldn't feel bad for using it.

Comment: I also think so.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** From $|f'(x)|\le1$ it follows that $|f(x)|\le|x+c|$ for some $c\in\Bbb R$.

Since $f(0)=f(2)=1$ we get that...

Comment: If $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ then you don't have $|f(x)| \leq |x+c|$.

Comment: I mean: take $c=1$ and consider everything on the interval $[0,2]$